# Does an EF6 DbContext rollback open transactions when it is disposed?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

If I dispose an EF6 DbContext and there is a transaction on it that is still open (i.e. not committed, not rolled back), what happens to the transaction? Is it rolled back immediately or does it remain open until the transaction object eventually gets disposed?

EDIT: Or is the behaviour provider-dependent?

Sample code:

```
  using (var dbContext = MagicallyCreateDbContext())
  {
    DbContextTransaction dbTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

    // do stuff ...

    // What happens if we don't invoke this?
    // dbTransaction.Commit();
  }
```

Comment: You don't need a transaction at all if you use DbContext as intended. `SaveChanges` will persist all pending changes using an internal transaction. What does `do stuff` do and why is an explicit transaction used at all? It's not needed. If `do stuff` makes multiple calls to `SaveChanges`, there's a bug

Comment: The current code is problematic - `dbTransaction` itself is `IDisposable` but is still alive (but orphaned` even after the DbContext is disposed. Transactions mean locking and you *really* don't want those locks to be maintained any longer than necessary. That's why connections and transactions are always created in `using` blocks - to close them and release any locks and resources as soon as possible. That's why explicit long-lived transactions are considered a bad idea since the 1990s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your first comment: No need for a transaction - noted.Your second comment: `dbTransaction` [...] is still alive: I see this as an answer to my question, i.e. in my terms it means the transaction remains "open". Could you write this as a StackOverflow answer, please?

Comment: The actual answer is `you're doing it wrong`. It doesn't matter if the actual *server-side* database transaction is rolled back immediately when the *client-side* connection is closed. It probably is. Or the connection remains open despite the call to `dispose` until the transaction is also garbage collected.  Neither of the two classes is meant to work this way though. Using an explicit transaction with EF is a **very strong smell**. Doing so *forces* a connection to open and remain open for a long time. Locks get accumulated, blocking other connections or deadlocking

Comment: DbContext is meant to work *dis*connected, just like every data access technology in all Microsoft stacks since the mid 1990s, when the disconnected Recordset was introduced and resulted in orders of magnitude better throughput due to reduced concurrency conflicts and deadlocks.  Opening a transaction forces DbContext to work in a connected mode, something it was never meant to do. The downsides are well known - even a couple of concurrent connections could lead do blocking and deadlocks, while the server simply waits for clients to stop blocking each other